# Mutate data frame via function in R

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

Sorry for the basic question, but I could not find an example in this forum to solve this question. I've tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969852/update-data-frame-via-function-doesnt-work) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230271/data-frame-passing-in-function-in-r).

I want to change / **create a new variable** in my data.frame via function in R and tidyverse:

Example:

```
crivo <- function(x) {
  x <<- x %>% 
    mutate(resp_1 = if_else(MEMO_RE01 == 0,"VN","FP")) %>% 
    mutate(resp_2 = if_else(MEMO_RE02 == 1,"VP","FN"))
  }
crivo(memo_re)
```

My data.frame name is **"memo_re"**, but I'll use this function to other datasets as well, just by changing the **x** argument. **R is creating a new data.frame named x** instead of creating a new variable in "memor_re" (original dataset). In other words, I want to assign a function to do that:

```
memo_re <- memo_re %>% mutate(resp_1 = if_else(MEMO_RE01 == 0,"VN","FP"))
```

But I need to change many datasets and because of that, I want to be able to specify which dataset I'll change.

reproducible code

```
library(tidyverse)
memo_re <- data.frame(MEMO_RE01=rep(c(0,1),100), MEMO_RE02=c(0,1))

crivo <- function(x) {
  x <<- x %>% 
    mutate(resp_1 = if_else(MEMO_RE01 == 0,"VN","FP")) %>% 
    mutate(resp_2 = if_else(MEMO_RE02 == 1,"VP","FN"))
}
crivo(memo_re)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. The code as you've provided it works just fine for me, though I think it's strange that you're just assigning `x` to the environment rather than returning it from the `crivo()` function.

Comment: Can you give data example?

Comment: Sure. You can simulate data.frame using this code: 
library(tidyverse)
memo_re <- data.frame(MEMO_RE01=rep(c(0,1),100), MEMO_RE02=c(0,1))

crivo <- function(x) {
  x <<- x %>% 
    mutate(resp_1 = if_else(MEMO_RE01 == 0,"VN","FP")) %>% 
    mutate(resp_2 = if_else(MEMO_RE02 == 1,"VP","FN"))
}
crivo(memo_re)

Comment: I edited my original post to clarify my question. Thanks.

Comment: you will have to use quosure format since in tidyverse function arguments are evaluated lazily using promise

Comment: Thanks, but could you please provide some link or reference? First time I heard about "quosure format". Thanks! @Onyambu

Comment: sorry you did ask for a link. Am so sorry. you can check [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R` is doing exactly what you've asked it to do. In your `crivo` function definition, you've written your function to *assign* the new data frame you've created called `x` to the `R` environment. That's what the `<<-` operator does. After running your code, use `ls()` to see what's in your environment, then look at `x`. You'll see everything is there, just as you've asked it to be, including the correctly mutate `x` dataframe.

```
> memo_re <- data.frame(MEMO_RE01=rep(c(0,1),100), MEMO_RE02=c(0,1))
> 
> crivo <- function(x) {
+   x <<- x %>% 
+     mutate(resp_1 = if_else(MEMO_RE01 == 0,"VN","FP")) %>% 
+     mutate(resp_2 = if_else(MEMO_RE02 == 1,"VP","FN"))
+ }
> crivo(memo_re)
> ls()
[1] "crivo"   "memo_re" "x"      
> head(x)
  MEMO_RE01 MEMO_RE02 resp_1 resp_2
1         0         0     VN     FN
2         1         1     FP     VP
3         0         0     VN     FN
4         1         1     FP     VP
5         0         0     VN     FN
6         1         1     FP     VP
```

Now, if you wanted to have `crivo()` return something that you could then assign any name you wanted, you should use

```
crivo <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    mutate(resp_1 = if_else(MEMO_RE01 == 0,"VN","FP"), 
           resp_2 = if_else(MEMO_RE02 == 1,"VP","FN"))
}
```

Note that I haven't used the `<<-` operator anywhere. As a result, the `crivo` fx will be returning the mutated `x` dataframe so that you could do

```
new <- memo_re %>% crivo()
```

This way, you can pipe anything you want to `crivo` and assign it to any new variable. Alternatively, if you just wanted to call the function on `memo_re`, you can do that too:

```
memo_re <- memo_re %>% crivo()
```

Note that the "classic" way to write a function is to use `return()` to specify what you want a fx to return. If you don't use `return()` (as I haven't above), `R` will return whatever is in the last line. Here, it's just the mutate dataframe.

Comment: Thanks much, @Steven, I want to know If it is possible to _instead of using memo_re <- memo_re %>% crivo()_ use something like _crivo(dataset I want to mutate)_ ?

Comment: Of course it is. Using `memo_re %>% crivo()` is the same as writing `crivo(memo_re)`. Either way, if you want to reuse whatever comes from `crivo()`, you'll need to assign the output to some variable.

Comment: Thanks, because English is not my first language, I think I'm not being precise. Is it possible to crivo(memo_re) get _"memo_re" dataset_, create a _new variable_ and update _this dataset_? I want to use _this same crivo function_ in _several datasets_. Example crivo(memo_re) will do that in "memo_re" dataset, but crivo(memo_2) will do this function in "memo_2). Thanks again, @Steven

Comment: So, `memo_re <- crivo(memo_re)` is unacceptable? As would be `memo_2 <- crivo(memo_2)`, etc.? You want `crivo(some_dataframe)` to mutate the `some_dataframe` dataframe and also update the *existing* `some_dataframe` in the current `R` environment? I think the latter is very bad software design and could have unintended consequences.

Comment: Your answer is totally acceptable! Thanks much! I just ask that for curiosity and to discover if this function will be possible to do in R! Thanks much again, @Steven !!